# solrCloud and group.query

Tags: solr, grouping, fieldcollapsing, solrcloud

today i build up an Solr Cloud System with 3 nodes, 3 shards and 3 replications.
After that I switched the application in order to use the new SolrCloud System instead the old one (singe instance).

While most of the features works fine, i found out that there are problems with field collapsing (or grouping).

Looking at the Solr documentation i don't find any informations about solrCloud and field collapsing problems.

Playing around with that feature in found out, that grouping with an `group.field=` works while `group.query=` generates an error.

For example
`http://localhost:9080/solr/archive/select/?group.limit=10&rows=10&group.query=car&group=true`

results in:

```
<lst name="error">
 <str name="trace">java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.solr.search.grouping.distributed.shardresultserializer.TopGroupsResultTransformer.transformToNative(TopGroupsResultTransformer.java:110)
at org.apache.solr.search.grouping.distributed.responseprocessor.TopGroupsShardResponseProcessor.process(TopGroupsShardResponseProcessor.java:80)
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.handleGroupedResponses(QueryComponent.java:620)
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.handleResponses(QueryComponent.java:603)
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:309)
at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1656)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:454)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:275)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:736)
 </str>
 <int name="code">500</int>
</lst>
```

Is this an known bug in Solr 4 Beta? Or is `group.field=` not supported in SolrCloud?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is being fixed in the next version of Solr

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-4150